# show that a set is not closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

Let
$$M:=\left\{ x+i \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\; |\; x \in (0,1) \right\}$$

not closed does not automatically mean open, right? For example, could I use the approach that every limit point of M is in M? But how could I calculate the limit points?

Comment: A door is open or closed, but in topology a set could be open, closed, both, or neither

Comment: If you're trying to show that it is not closed then you only need to find a single limit point not contained in $M$. You could also show that its complement is not open.

Comment: Hint: Show that $\mathtt{cl}(M) = M\cup S$ where $S=\{iy\in\mathbb{C}:|y|\leq 1\}$ using sequences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, a set may be neither open nor closed.

**Hint:** If $x=\frac1{n\pi}$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$, what is $x+i\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$?

Comment: thank you, if $x=\frac{1}{n\pi}$, then $x+i sin(\frac{1}{x})$=$\frac{1}{n\pi}+0$ but how I can I deduct from it that this is not in (0,1)?

Comment: What matters is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n\pi}=0\notin M$.

Comment: thank you very much, I did not know that n could converge to infinity